# Applescript to find and replace xml using TextWrangler

Tags: html, xml, grep, applescript

How can I achieve automating the replacing of `<ContactsWWW>www.site.com</ContactsWWW>` with `<a href="http://www.site.com">www.site.com</a>` where "www.site.com" differs between numerous xml files?

EDIT: Solved thusly;
`replace "<ContactsWWW>((?i)(http|ftp|www)(\\S+)|(\\S+) (\\.gov|\\.us|\\.net|\\.com|\\.edu|\\.org|\\.biz))</ContactsWWW>" using "<a href='http://\\1'>\\1</a>" options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:true, match words:false, extend selection:false}`

Comment: Try TextyWrangler's grep feature and GUI scripting. Post you code here. Then ask for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep find and replace xml into anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425046/grep-find-and-replace-xml-into-anchor-tag)

Comment: Yes that link was mine but got closed, I asked again here and tried to be more concise.

Comment: You shouldn't ask your question again but edit it to have it re-opened.

Comment: OK thank you I'll know for future questions. Feel free to delete that previous one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk` this should do:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/ContactsWWW/ {print "<a href=\"http://"$3"</a>"}' file
<a href="http://www.site.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, any chance you could break it down a bit for me please? At the moment my Applescript will accept a file dropped onto it, load TextWrangler and run a series of find a replace statements. How would I fit this is in, my other statements use 'replace' and 'using'.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript/sed solution. Tested with .txt files. Should work with .xml files too.(?)

```
do shell script "
oIFS=$IFS
IFS='\t\n'
for theFile in $(find " & quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder) & " -type f -name '*.xml');do
sed -i '' -e 's/<ContactsWWW>\\(.*\\)<\\/ContactsWWW>/<a href=\"http:\\/\\/\\1\">\\1<\\/a>/' $theFile
done
IFS=$oIFS
"
```